# How to add self signed certificate to certificate bundle?

Tags: ssl, certificate, openssl, curl

How to add self signed certificate to certificate bundle so that the Curl http client can verify the self signed certificate as valid one?

Comment: I just added the server.crt file path to CURLOPT_CAINFO.Now I get the error 51: SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own ca instead:

- generate your own ca
- generate a cert for your server signed by your own ca
- add this ca to the certificate bundle

Comment: It sounds so simple when you put it like that... ;)

Comment: I've added the self signed CA certificate to the bundle and run c_rehash. Now I get the error 35: SSL connect error! further error message I could get into is : SSL routines:SSL3_GET_MESSAGE: excessive message size!  I don't know what the heck that means? :(